# Conditional code based on generic type parameter with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, types

I have a method in C# which receives a generic type as argument:

```
private void DoSomething<T>(T param)
{
    //...
}
```

I need to perform different things depending on what type is `param` of. I know I can achieve it with several `if` sentences, like this:

```
private void DoSomething<T>(T param)
{
    if (param is TypeA)
    {
        // do something specific to TypeA case

    } else if (param is TypeB)
    {
        // do something specific to TypeB case

    } else if ( ... )
    {
        ...
    }

    // ... more code to run no matter the type of param
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Maybe with `switch-case` or another approach that I'm not aware of?

Comment: In general, if you're doing something inherently type-specific, a generic method is the wrong tool. Perhaps create an method with type-specific overloads, which calls the generic method upon completion?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: this might make for some good reading [Constraints on Type Params](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot, I also thought on overloads; I was looking for different ideas and alternatives. You are right, is the way to go. Nevertheless, I got interesting feedback from every answer, thank you all (+1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a specific method for a particular type.

```
    private void DoSomething<T>(T param)
    {
        //...
    }

    private void DoSomething(int param) { /* ... */ }

    private void DoSomething(string  param) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use overloading instead of generics.

Answer (score 4):

If project/logic structure allows it would be nice to move DoSomething into T and describe it with IDoSomething interface. This way you can write:

```
private void DoSomething<T>(T param) where T:IDoSomething
{
    param.DoSomething()
}
```

If that's not an option then you can setup dictionary of rules

```
var actionsByType = new Dictionary<Type, Action<T /*if you neeed that param*/>(){
   { Type1, DoSomething1 },
   { Type2, DoSomething2 },
   /..
}
```

and in your method you can call:

```
private void DoSomething<T>(T param){
  //some checks if needed
  actionsByType[typeof(T)](param/*if param needed*/);
}
```

Comment: I was about to go with your first idea, pretty nice! But my project structure didn't allow it. The second is also good, but I'll try with simple overloads first. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before if its a simple case use overloading. Anything stranger you can adapt this (its quick and dirty apologies).

```
class Program
{

    interface IDoSomething<T>
    {
        void DoSomething(T param);
    }

    class Test : IDoSomething<int>, IDoSomething<string>
    {
        public void DoSomething(int param)
        {

        }

        public void DoSomething(string param)
        {

        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        DoSomething(4);

    }

    static void DoSomething<T>(T param)
    {
        var test = new Test();
        var cast = test as IDoSomething<T>;
        if (cast == null) throw new Exception("Unhandled type");
        cast.DoSomething(param);
    }
}
```