# How do you use `switch` in C# to conditionally branch based on only a type parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, switch-statement, type-parameter

My context is that I'm building a simple factory method for creating instances of derived types of a given base type.  The factory method only takes a type parameter, i.e. doesn't have any arguments.  This is obviously possible with an `if`-`else if` construct:

```
public Vehicle Create<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Car))
        return new Car(); // just an example; could be more complex logic.
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Truck))
        return new Truck(); // just an example; could be more complex logic.
    else
        throw new ArgumentException(
            $"The type {typeof(T).Name} is not known by this method.");
}
```

It's well-known by now how to use pattern matching in C# (as of C# 7.0) to branch based on the type of a *variable* but this doesn't work for a type parameter:

```
switch (T) { ... } // error: "'T' is a type, which is not valid in the given context"
```

or...

```
switch (typeof(T))
{
    case Car c: ... 
    // err: "An expression of type 'Type' cannot be handled by a pattern of type 'Car'"
}
```

So I'd like to know **if it's possible to use `switch` to achieve the same result?**

---

Research: I'm surprised this hasn't been asked before, but I can't find it.  I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802325/switch-case-and-generics-checking) which has a name and a few answers that come pretty close but it's dealing with (numeric) value types and methods that have an argument of type `T` -- the generic type parameter.  Similarly, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003597/conditional-code-based-on-generic-type-parameter-with-c-sharp) also uses an argument.

Comment: No - I'm afraid you're stuck with if/else. At least remember that the JIT knows this pattern, and can optimize for it.

Comment: Well, I answered my own question, so it *is* possible.

Comment: Your answer is just abusing a switch to write an if/else - I'm not sure you can really claim that's a viable alternative to if/else! I could write an if/else using exception filters. Does that mean I should? Absolutely not.

Comment: [switch on type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298976/is-there-a-better-alternative-than-this-to-switch-on-type) with a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/299001/1515209)

Comment: You could also create a `Dictionary<Type, Func<Vehicle>>` or something, of course.

Comment: @canton7 -- that wouldn't be nearly the same level of efficiency -- overhead -- as a switch or an else-if, so that's a silly suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your attitude. You ask for suggestions, then call them "silly" but defend your own suggestion with "some people might prefer doing this". If you're going to shoot down every else's suggestions, but defend your own to the death, why bother asking the question in the first place?

Comment: Also, an if/else is O(n) (ignoring any JIT optimizations), but a dictionary is O(1). For a large number of items, the dictionary will probably beat the pants off an if/else. Use `RuntimeTypeHandle` for bonus speed points.

Comment: Okay I misunderstood the intent of your comment.  I thought it was solely to point out that you thought my answer was absurd.  My mistake (honestly).

Comment: @qujck -- you misunderstood the question.  It's not about variable type, it's about type parameters (generics).

Comment: See [Is there a better alternative than this to 'switch on type'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55573781/266143) for many more absurd suggestions, such as `where T : new() /* ... */ switch (new T()) { ... }`.

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#type-pattern

Comment: @CodeCaster -- what does the question you think this is a dupe of have to do with generic type parameters?  You really think this is an *exact duplicate* of that question?

Answer (score 2):

I know your question specifically asked about using the switch statement, but another alternative would be to create a dictionary of factories keyed on the type.

You should note that at this point, you are doing an operation similar to dependency injection.  You are asking for a Vehicle of type X and risking a run-time error if the Create method does not have the information needed to Create a Vehicle of type X.

```
public class Car : Vehicle { }
public class Truck : Vehicle { }

public abstract class Vehicle
{
    private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, Func<Vehicle>> vehicleFactories = new Dictionary<Type, Func<Vehicle>>
    {
        { typeof(Car), () => new Car() },
        { typeof(Truck), () => new Truck() }
    };

    public static Vehicle Create<T>() where T : Vehicle, new()
    {
        if (vehicleFactories.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var factory))
        {
            return factory();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                $"The type {typeof(T).Name} is not known by this method.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Note that I'm not making any statement as to whether this is good or bad.  It's entirely to show that it's possible to do it.

This can be accomplished in C# 7.0 or later using a `switch` block with pattern matching and the `when` keyword:

```
public Vehicle Create<T>() where T : Vehicle
{
    switch (true)
    {
        case bool x when typeof(T) == typeof(Car): return new Car();
        case bool x when typeof(T) == typeof(Truck): return new Truck();
        default: throw new ArgumentException(
            $"The type {typeof(T).Name} is not known by this method.");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just horrible. Why would you ever want to use this in your code?

Comment: @PatrickHofman -- it's just a POC, and that's totally your opinion unless you can back it up with something factual.

Comment: There's some elegance to it.  It's the type of thing that grows on you.

Comment: Sorry, but as canton7 wrote: Your answer is just abusing a switch to write an if/else. That's just it.

Comment: But it *is* possible.  This question isn't about whether it's good or bad.  It's entirely about whether it's possible.

Comment: So is the question actually "What esoteric ways are there to write an if/else without using an explicit if/else"? I can come up with some horrible answers to that...

Comment: You can simplify your one a bit with `switch ((object)null) { case null when ...; case null when ...; }`

Comment: @PatrickHofman -- some people might prefer using a switch instead of an if-else.  So what?

Comment: @PatrickHofman This is a Q&A by the same person.  You don't get to define what they consider production.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 No. I am just judging the usefulness of this answer.

Comment: @PatrickHofman -- the answer simply points out an alternative to "if-else".  Whether it's an abuse of C# is simply a matter of opinion.  Unless you can point to some other place this was previously mentioned, I think this could be the only place and thus has *some* degree of utility to *someone*, and that is a mere fact.

Comment: The problem isn't if/then vs. switch. It's runtime type-checking that will produce unpredictable runtime errors. If I write `Create<Bicycle>()` and it compiles because `Bicycle : Vehicle`, but then at *runtime* it says, "Oops, not *that* type of `vehicle`", that's bad. In most - not all - cases if we're doing this sort of runtime type checking something has gone wrong.